# How can I force a branch update?

Tags: git, github

This is a question about git branch and git pull.

The current situation is as follows.

1. A "release" branch has been created at the remote repository.
   (remote)
2. Pulled the "release" branch locally.
   (local)
3. Removed "release" branch from remote repository.
   There is still a "release" branch locally.
   (remote)
4. A "release" branch has been created at the remote repository with new features.
   (remote)
5. I want the local "release" branch to be updated with the new "release" branch at the remote repository.
   (local)

git pull doesn't work because the branch name is the same but the branch was created differently.

What's a good way?

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete your local branch then create it again, that will do it for you. Example:

```
git checkout master
git branch -D releaseBranch
git checkout -b releaseBranch
```

Answer (score 0):

just fetch your remote release branch to your local release branch. 

`git checkout master`
`git fetch <your-remote-repo> <your-remote-release-branch>:<your-local-release-branch>`
`git checkout <your-local-release-branch>`

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in two steps:

```
git fetch the-remote # fetch information about the position of branches/tags on the remote
git branch -f release the-remote/release # set the position of local release to whatever point the-remote/release is at... no merging/rebasing involved
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you don't have any local changes you want to keep, you can just do a reset

```
git reset --hard origin/releaseBranch
```